# Stored Procedure called via Excel data connection fails

Tags: sql, excel, stored-procedures

I have table in a Excel 2007 workbook. The table has an external SQL data connection to a stored procedure. Inside the stored procedure I'd like to clear and populate an intermediate table before querying data from it.

The stored procedure works if I don't have the `INSERT` statement in it (I insert the data outside Excel), but as soon I try to insert into my temporary table in the stored procedure, I get an error `"The query did not run or the database could not be opened"`.

What's interesting too is that despite the error, the insert inside the stored procedure still gets executed - the data is there after the error. Anybody knows how I can do the insert without triggering the error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I did some more digging and I came across this article that contained the answer:
[Running Advanced SQL Stored Procedures from Excel](http://datapigtechnologies.com/blog/index.php/running-advanced-sql-stored-procedures-from-excel/)

Basically before my insert I have to put SET NOCOUNT ON and after the insert, I add SET NOCOUNT OFF.